# Rails3: one controller many partials for form data submission

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I am not sure if this is the best approach but I have a controller that originally I intended to control a show index that renders many partials on it (a header partial and then, has some if else magic to render different partials based on the step the user is in in filling out a form... a form has many sections across several pages).  I think ultimately ajax is the way to go but I am not even to that point yet.  I am not sure this is the right way to do it, so I guess that is what I am asking... is the many different partials to one controller the way ?  or does each "page" of form data have to be broken out into its own controller?  allowing the user to fill out form (check boxes, comment section) and click "next" passing the model of the data they are filling out along the way and saving that model in each next?

Comment: Sounds like you need a state machine to handle this.  There are various gems written for just this purpose, as well as the one included in rails...

Comment: okay, any names off hand for me to google to start researching this?  The process is simple enough just not sure how to do this in a rails way.  Worst case, I can break it all out into individual controllers with index/show views etc but that just doesn't seem the correct way to do this.

Comment: Look at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/state_machines.html.  The [state_machine](https://rubygems.org/gems/state_machine) gem seems most popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U may not need several controllers, but 1 controller with some actions may be a good start. =)

Then each action should load only the partial it needs. like u can give the action name to the partial, making easy to know which partial to render.

Or maybe u can try to use [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked/).

There is a [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast) for it.

Comment: I tried this but I must of done it wrong.... can a partial be rendered to a specific div, does a reload happen of the page?  Would i NEED ajax to do this?  Routing thus far has been my issue.  I have a show action in my current controller that comes from another controller with the model data passed in, this is right! then when i take it over though and want to start navigating these form pages...that methodolgy doesnt fit anymore...

Comment: U will have to create another action for each new form page. And consequently a new route for each. Then on each one u will render a different partial. See my post edit.

Comment: going with wicked.  It fits perfectly, though I am having a few issues passing it an id (the rails cast on it shows him using it with a current_user method and I need to pass an object ID, this has proven difficult thus far as the params[:id] is reserved for the step page its going to) oh well so far so good..

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use a method to decide which partial to render.
Use this example or do some meta programming.

```
  class YourController < ApplicationController
       def index
          render :partial => partial_selector(param)
       end

       private
       def partial_selector param
          #logic to decide what partial do render
          #returns the partial name
       end
 end
```